# cakephp: creating new records from other controller

Tags: cakephp, model

I'm going to create 50 temp/dummy rows inside my model database. My problems is how can I create and save new records in my DB? 
 Assume my model Random containts columns (id,randomValue,...).

Comment: Are you really asking for [**how to save data**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html), or am I missing something here?

Comment: @ndm: I meant how to create new records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function addNew() {
    $this->autoRender = false; // We don't render a view in this example
    $moduleSize = 50;
    $count = $moduleSize;
    while ($count > 0) {
        $random_number = rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
        //check if duplicate
        if ($this->checkIfDuplicateSerial($random_number)) {
            //nothing to be done
        } else {
            $this->Random->create(array('randomValue' => $random_number));
            $this->Random->save();
            $this->Random->clear(); //to init new one
            $count--;
        }
    }
    $this->response->body('Inserted' . $moduleSize . 'Random Numbers');
}
```